# is there any way to change the path of tinymce files needed?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, tinymce, rte

I am using a tiny mce html editor in a aspx page but i have a problem,all its needed files must place beside my page exactly. i mean the tiny mce files and folders and my aspx page must be at the same directory.
it not good and i want to change the path of needed file,is there any option or solution to change the path of these files?

i found some option but they are not usable.

```
        // Example content CSS (should be your site CSS)
        content_css: "../App_Themes/TinuMCE.css",

        // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
        template_external_list_url: "lists/template_list.js",
        external_link_list_url: "lists/link_list.js",
        external_image_list_url: "lists/image_list.js",
        media_external_list_url: "lists/media_list.js",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i can not get any way to do that , i think it is impossible,ah...

Answer (score 1):

They do not need to be in the same directory. All you need to do is to include the tiny_mce.js in your html page/html template.

Comment: i did it,but it gone with errors. can not find the ... (i check it in firebug)

Comment: You're doing something wrong; examine those errors. What he said is enough and pretty much the only way.

Comment: in this suite , the tinyMCE needed files must be beside of the page you want to use TinyMCE in it, and this is bad  an i want to change its needed files path but i can not :(

Comment: can't you just place the tinymce code on both possible locations?